# I want to open Msconfig from a button on my GUI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In my line of work I use msconfig a lot and I'm wanting to create a tool with various buttons on it so I can easily access my most commonly used programs. I'm using the Win32API to create the GUI and buttons, however I am having trouble getting msconfig to run. In my program I have

```
void callMsconfig()
{
ShellExecute(NULL,(LPCWSTR)L"open", (LPCWSTR)L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\msconfig.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}
```

and an action statement so when the button is pressed the function is called. I've tried replacing ShellExecute() with system() and CreateProcess(). I've also replaced "open" with "runas" and the most I've gotten is the error saying C:\Windows\System32\msconfig.exe cannot be found when I know it is there because I've checked. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Windows 10 Home if that helps any.

Comment: You compiled a 32-bit application and run it on 64-bit Windows. *system32* gets redirected to *SysWOW64*, and there is no msconfig.exe. Compile a 64-bit application, or disable folder virtualization.

Comment: You should dump those unnecessary casts and stop using C-style casts in C++.

Comment: Thank you for your help linspectable!

Comment: In a 32bit app running inside of WOW64, you don't need to disable virtualization, you can just skip it by using `C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\msconfig.exe` instead. This is documented behavior:

Comment: [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx): "*32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting `%windir%\Sysnative` for `%windir%\System32`. WOW64 recognizes `Sysnative` as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the `Sysnative` alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.*"

Comment: Windows key + R, msconfig

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a 32bit app that is running inside of the WOW64 emulator on 64bit systems, the `C:\Windows\System32\` folder is silently redirected by WOW64 to the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` folder, which does not have an `msconfig.exe` file.  You need to account for that.  Either create a 64bit executable, or use the `Sysnative` alias in 32bit code that runs inside of WOW64.  `Sysnative` is documented on MSDN:

[File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx):

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting `%windir%\Sysnative` for `%windir%\System32`. WOW64 recognizes `Sysnative` as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the `Sysnative` alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <shlwapi.h>

void callMsconfig()
{
    BOOL IsWow64 = FALSE;
    WCHAR szCmdLine[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &IsWow64);
    if (IsWow64)
    {
        GetWindowsDirectoryW(szCmdLine, MAX_PATH);
        PathAppendW(szCmdLine, L"Sysnative");
    }
    else
    {
        GetSystemDirectoryW(szCmdLine, MAX_PATH);
    }
    PathAppendW(szCmdLine, L"msconfig.exe");

    ShellExecuteW(NULL, NULL, szCmdLine, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}
```

However, do note that if UAC is enabled and you try to launch `msconfig.exe` from a 32bit process running inside of WOW64, the 32bit process MUST be running elevated or else `ShellExecute()` (and `CreateProcess()`) will fail to find the file correctly. I don't know why, but that is how it works.  UAC Elevation is not required when launching `msconfig.exe` from a 64bit process.

If you don't want to elevate your entire program, you will have to make it launch a separate elevated process that can then launch `msconfig.exe`.  You could just have the program launch a second copy of itself with a command-line parameter so it knows to just launch `msconfig.exe` and then exit itself.  To launch an elevated process, you can use `ShellExecute()` specifying the `runas` verb.

Comment: Why not simply remove all of this, and compile a 64 bit process?

Comment: FWIW, msconfig does require elevation on 64 bit. Because it's a system executable, then the UAC setting that permits system executables to run elevated without the consent dialog allows it to run elevated without you giving consent.  But I guess when running from sysnative, the consent dialog will always be shown. Again, yet more reason to simply switch to 64 bit and be done with it.

Comment: What I meant was that a 64bit process that launches msconfig does not need to be running elevated in order to launch it. And there is no consent dialog shown if an elevated 32bit process launches it.

Comment: A non-elevated 64 bit process that launches msconfig will lead to the consent dialog being shown if the UAC settings are set to the maximum setting, *always notify*. I presume you are running on default settings, the next rung down.